# PHP unset not working in for each

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, first time posting here. I've looked everywhere for an answer, and as clear as the answers are that have already been provided, they are not working. I've never been stuck like this. Basically it's just unset that is not working. My "user_id" variable is being processed perfectly fine, as well as the exploding values.

```
while($publisher_info = mysql_fetch_array($explode_publishers)){
    $publisher_members = explode(",", $publisher_info['publisher_members']);
}

$developer_members = array_filter($publisher_members);
foreach($developer_members as $developer_name => &$developer_id){    
    if($developer_id == $user_id){
        unset($developer_members[$developer_name]);
    }
}
```

This still shows the ID which is in this case '1', as I am testing from the first users account.

Thanks in advance!

Real Code:

```
$final_dev = array_filter($publisher_members);
foreach($final_dev as $publisher_data => &$val){

if($val == $u_main_id){
    unset($final_dev[$publisher_data]);
}

$name_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = '$val'");
while($get_from_name = mysql_fetch_array($name_result))
{
    $usr_name = $get_from_name['user_name'];
}
    echo "<option value=" . $usr_name . ">" . $usr_name . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: You are sure the developer id is even once equal to user id?

Comment: For sure, I have tested that in multiple ways.

Comment: put semicolon in your unset line.

Comment: Add `var_dump($developer_members, $user_id);` before `foreach` and show output. I bet there is no such an id in array.

Comment: Did that and I get: array(2) { [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "67" } string(1) "1"

Comment: Also, looks like you actually wanted to call `array_flip` instead of `array_filter`. Otherwise foreach var names don't make sense.

Comment: Sidenote: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Comment: Ok, now please tell how you check that "This still shows the ID".

Comment: ksimka, I basically have a query in this foreach that finds their username from their ID and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Also, array_flip brings back off numbers that aren't even in the array.

Comment: Doh... So, that's not your actual code. Please, show your **actual** code, because that one in your post works just fine.

Comment: Are you passing value by reference?  you have used "&$developer_id".

Comment: lol ok hope this isn't confusing

Comment: Can't figure out where to post the code...

Comment: try identical $developer_id === $user_id and check if condition is true or not.

Comment: Ravi, I have done this. It comes back true.

Comment: Still confused, looking for help.... lol

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what are you trying to do here, but try to use `continue` instead of `unset()`.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is make it so that the username of the user session which you are logged into doesn't show in the select option. I need the ID to not get placed in the foreach so that when I query for the username it doesn't how.

Comment: Alright so I tried continue and it worked perfectly. The answer below is not the right answer at all.. poor Riggs... Thanks! Although you could have been more clear on how to use continue... Reading stackoverflow is like reading an ikea manual.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what `$user_id` you want to find but that is a value and not a key of your array, you could flip the array to swap the keys with the values and visa versa, and then find that specific developers name, then use that to remove the specific entry of the original array.

Please bear in mind I dont know what you actual array keys and values are called, so this is an example, that I hope makes sense to you

```
$temp = array_flip($developer_members);

$dev_name = $temp[$user_id];

unset( $developer_members[$dev_name] );
```

Comment: Appreciate it, I'll have to look into this..tomorrow as it is 6am now :(... my brain is on fire, as I also have the flu.

Comment: Whiskey asperin and hot lemon, it may not work but the whiskey makes it so you dont care

Comment: So what is a $temp variable for? I don't have a $temp in my code so I'm confused...

Comment: Thats just to hold the flipped array temporarily so you can use the `$user_id` as a key to get the $dev_name` out and then use it as the key to the original array for the unset operation

Answer (score -1):

using "continue;" was the way to do it.

```
if($val == $u_main_id){
    continue;
}
```